# How do I get a result returned from mysql to php using a stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

If I am using PHP without a stored procedure I would write something like

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from whatever");
```

but what happens if the "select * from whatever" is in a stored procedure?
how then do I get the $result? 
Do I need to write it in such a way that it returns a cursor to php?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908311/how-to-return-a-table-from-a-stored-procedure-to-php

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation I found that PHP has a statement class which works with statements in a similar way to using plain sql and it's documentation is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) also I found some code to help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54773890/return-mysql-stored-procedure-result-set-using-php) but the most important thing I learned in all this is that NO I don't need to create a return variable with a return value to return the data from the query. The query results are automatically available from the prepared statement and because I am just doing the SQL side of things that's all I need to know so far